# Tkinter: How to make a system tray application?

Tags: python, user-interface, system, tkinter, tray

i have a small application. I want my target users(windows,linux) to be able to start and exit the application from the system tray. I intend to use Tkinter because of its low footprint but, i dont know how to implement it.

Can tkinter do this or are there better alternatives. I need a GUI library that won't change my 1MB program to a 5MB program.

Please sample codes will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I don't know any direct examples but I found a TCL/Tk extension to use the systray over here http://wiki.tcl.tk/4090 and a [page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/How%20Tkinter%20can%20exploit%20Tcl/Tk%20extensions) on the wiki giving information on how to use TCL/Tk extensions from Tkinter.

On a more general note, you might want to consider using a more "advanced" toolkit (like wx) that provides things like systray usage etc. natively.

Comment: Seems that a skilled tkinter programmer downvoted you :)

Comment: Found the old googlecode repo imported at github https://github.com/kurnevsky/tktray. Have fun. For more info, wrapper and usage demo you can look at https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2010-April/002208.html - I've run tests and Python code and it works.