# tkinter: How to make a system tray application not using winico?

Tags: python, tkinter, pywin32, system-tray

Question [Tkinter: How to make a system tray application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385656/tkinter-how-to-make-a-system-tray-application) and other searching results show that this can be done using winico.  But winico doesn't support x64. Since most people use x64 PC(including me) now, winico no longer works.

There must be some other ways to do this not using winico. I know that PyWin32 works, but I don't know how. Can someone just give me an example? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this,which works fine(though need to change some code)

http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html

Comment: How do you configure `pywin32` with `tkinter`?