# Is there any way to minimize python application to system tray with Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, system

I'm making a simple GUI Application using Tkinter(Python). And I want it to minimize to System Tray and keep running. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You can try [pystray](https://pystray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimize the window tkinter in the windows system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56109891/minimize-the-window-tkinter-in-the-windows-system-tray)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68419020/17990633) answer, you can use `root.withdraw()` method or packages like `pystray`.

> The entire solution consists of two parts:
>
> 1. Hide/restore tkinter window
> 2. Create/delete systray object

#### 1:

```
#import stuff...

root = tk.Tk()

root.withdraw() #hide
root.deiconify() #show again
```

*Also remember to use `mainloop()`*

---

#### 2:

You can use packages like pystray,...

I don't know much about pystray or whatever like that, but you can follow its [documentation](https://pystray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) and try its examples.