# How to add system tray to my tkinter application and avoid using lots of pywin32 code(Just on windows)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I find three ways to make system tray:

1. [Tkinter: How to make a system tray application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385656/tkinter-how-to-make-a-system-tray-application)
   This answer was a little abstract, especially for we didn't study about tcl.
2. [How to build a SystemTray app for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494739/how-to-build-a-systemtray-app-for-windows)The accepted answer used lots of pywin32 code which looked a little tedious.
3. [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082417/11811255) mentioned `infi.systray` and `pystray`.I found them need to use some extra threads to create the system tray by looking up  documentation.But refer to ["All Tcl commands need to originate from the same thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703502/threads-and-tkinter/26703844#26703844),I think it is not a good practice to call `.deiconify()` in other threads.

Could someone show me a minimal example to use `winico` or something else without using extra thread?

Answer (score 3):

The solution with [`Winico`](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/winico/winico.html):

An example GIF image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTX1D.jpg

You should download it firstly.

Download :[32-bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tktable/files/winico/), [64-bit](https://fossil.mpcjanssen.nl/winico/dir?ci=tip)(It is a little hard to find it,I finally find it in the deep of Google.Just download the `pkg` in the website and rename it as `Winico` is okay.)

After download it, you need to move it to `yourPythonPath/tcl`

---

> How to use it to make a system tray with `Winico`?

A minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.trayMenu = None

    def on_closing(self):
        if not self.trayMenu: # when system tray is not exists.
            selection = messagebox.askyesnocancel("Tips", "Quit directly?\nYes : Quit.\nNo:Minimize to system tray.")  # "Yes" will return True, "Cancel" will return None, "No" will return False.
            if selection: # when select yes, quit the app directly.
                self.destroy()
            elif selection == False: # Minimize to system tray.
                # make a system tray
                self.withdraw()
                # use bulitin tk.Menu

                # The work about "Winico"
                self.tk.call('package', 'require', 'Winico') # use the tcl "winico", make sure the folder of "winico" is in the same path.
                icon = self.tk.call('winico', 'createfrom', '2.ico') # this is the icon on the system tray.
                self.tk.call('winico', 'taskbar', 'add', icon, # set the icon
                            '-callback', (self.register(self.menu_func), '%m', '%x', '%y'), # refer to winico documentation.
                            '-pos', 0,
                            '-text', u'jizhihaoSAMA’s Tool') # the hover text of the system tray.

                # About menu
                self.trayMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
                self.trayMenu.add_command(label="Show my app", command=self.deiconify)

                # You could also add a cascade menu
                cascadeMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
                cascadeMenu.add_command(label="Casacde one", command=lambda :print("You could define it by yourself"))
                cascadeMenu.add_command(label="Cascade two")
                self.trayMenu.add_cascade(label="Other", menu=cascadeMenu)

                self.trayMenu.add_separator() # you could add a separator

                self.trayMenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.destroy)

                # you could also add_command or add_checkbutton for what you want
            else: # This is cancel operation
                pass
        else:
            self.withdraw() # when system tray exists, hide the window directly.

    def menu_func(self, event, x, y):
        if event == 'WM_RBUTTONDOWN': # Mouse event, Right click on the tray.Mostly we will show it.
            self.trayMenu.tk_popup(x, y) # pop it up on this postion
        if event == 'WM_LBUTTONDOWN': # Mouse event, Left click on the tray,Mostly we will show the menu.
            self.deiconify() # show it.
        # All the Mouse event:

        # WM_MOUSEMOVE
        # WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        # WM_LBUTTONUP
        # WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK
        # WM_RBUTTONDOWN
        # WM_RBUTTONUP
        # WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK
        # WM_MBUTTONDOWN
        # WM_MBUTTONUP
        # WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

---

> What should I do when I want to use `Pyinstaller` to pack it?

In the spec file:

```
a = Analysis(['script.py'],
             pathex=['xxxx'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('Winico', 'winico')], # You need to revise this
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
```

Or just do:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "Winico;winico" script.py
```

---

Refer to [a Chinese blog](https://www.cnblogs.com/little-groot/p/7852924.html),I email the blog writer and get some help from him.

Not sure whether it could work on Linux or Unix.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, a couple of questions: when adding "Winico;winico" to the binary data, this refers to a file 'winico' within the 'Winico' folder, which we placed in the tcl, as far as I understand? In my case it keeps looking for it in my current folder (where my script and spec file are), and of course it can not find it.